# i have a hash code which i gotta write at java

Tags: encryption, hash, hashcode

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
```

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class EmailDecoder {
public static void main(String[] args) {
String encodedEmail = "f894e71e1551d1833a977df952d0cc9de44a1f9669fbf97d51309a2c6574d5eaa746cd" +
"eb9ee1a5dfc771d280d33e5672e48a0b49e999dc7d88f3e7073040596e98687c4d1" +
"730f3ac2fb2fe4f3e2fba56af628f412d7fdd02405f755a7a9ed59f2fd71f28ca8fc7500f" +
.....5098b5499d";

```
    String decodedEmail = decodeEmail(encodedEmail);
    System.out.println(decodedEmail);
}

public static String decodeEmail(String encodedEmail) {
    StringBuilder decodedEmail = new StringBuilder();
    int length = encodedEmail.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 64) {
        String substring = encodedEmail.substring(i, Math.min(i + 64, length));
        String reversed = reverseHash(substring);
        String character = reversed.substring(reversed.length() - 2);
        decodedEmail.append(character);
    }

    return decodedEmail.toString();
}

public static String reverseHash(String hash) {
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] bytes = new BigInteger(1, hexToBytes(hash)).toByteArray();
        byte[] digest = md.digest(bytes);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (byte b : digest) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

public static byte[] hexToBytes(String hex) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[hex.length() / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        int index = i * 2;
        int j = Integer.parseInt(hex.substring(index, index + 2), 16);
        bytes[i] = (byte) j;
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

}

Comment: It's plausible that the email has an even number of characters and ends in `.com` in which case the final two pairs will be `.c` and `om`. Applying the hash function they provide, does that match the final characters?

Comment: @RichardHeap you are right, it gotta be .com, but i dont know how to decrypte the last(.com) ones?

Comment: 1 - have you confirmed that you can hash Nano to `411dedd4fa525b61bffc4241266fb4634eef4018f94f265c6ba447d32be74ce6` - until you can do that there's no point continuing. 2 - what do you know about hashes (spoiler - they are NOT encryption)? For example, are they reversable? So, is this a decryption question, or something else? 3 - What's the significance of them telling you that each pair of letters is made up of characters from the letters, digits and `@._`? (PS - it turns out not to be .com - that's a red herring)

Comment: The answer is like '.....@nano.com.tr'. You need to write a simple program to reverse hash each 32 character substring. This is clearly a test to see if you can write a program to decode the longer hex string of 17 md5 hashes. Ordinarily, reverse hashing is very difficult and not technically feasible in the general case, but with just 2 characters 'encoded' in each hash it is trivial for a program.

Comment: @RichardHeap: I get `7af8f6243a524e0d551759d56095bb8af6f0c5daf82a4a39b0861a3c9fc3cb89` for `Nano`.

Comment: @berry.11 I don't think it would be fair on your interviewer or good SO practice for me to give you my code. It's PHP and all it does is declare a function getchars() which takes in the md5 hash and compares it with every two character hash like your question describes, returning the two characters from the matching hash. The main part of the program loops over the input string and feeds the 17 hashes to the function and prints the output. It isn't a difficult task. I don't know Java though so I can't help you debug your code. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simon Goater had it right, you need to upvote his answer in the comments.

Here's my output (as an arraylist):

[*, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, @n, an, o., co, m., tr]

(redacted for Simon)

Comment: may you share code

Comment: Well we should ask Simon first to see if it's OK.

Comment: which language did u use?

Comment: I LOOOOVE Java!  So that's what I use.  What nation do you represent?  Like where do you reside?

Comment: i love it too, i had written a code at java but it didnt work well could u please help to solve. i  am bulgarian

Comment: That's great!  Java's a good language to work with.  Anyway, how important is it?  I could email it to you, given you post your email here for a little bit.  You could accept my answer, which points to Simon.  Want to give that a try?  Ill copy and paste code, no attachments, lol.

Comment: i get that. could you just share the code without the hssh code all? becuse it is important 

Comment: I'm adamant about asking Simon.  It's a neat little problem and he should have the credit.  I personally don't mind sharing.

Comment: We could talk about your code.  Want to do that?

Comment: sure. what is the problem about my code?

Comment: hi, simon didn't share the code cos of its php. could you chare your java code

Comment: @berry.11 getting some code that solves the problem will not help you to get the job. When the interviewer asks how you solved it and probes into questions about what your thought processes were, what issues you had, how you solved those issues, etc - you won't be able to answer. Worse, you won't be able to answer the follow up questions like "why were you able to crack the code - was there a weakness in the crypto system that helped you?" and "how could that have been improved" etc.

Comment: Perhaps it's inappropriate to paste my code here.  But if you have other questions on the topic, you could ask.  It's an important and interesting field.